# File's Data keeps getting overwritten by function

Tags: python, file-io

for some reason I am running into an issue where my function call seems to be overwriting the data read in from the file without me asking it to. I am trying to get the sum of the original list but I keep getting the sum of the squared list.

**CODE:**

```
def toNumbers(strList):
    for i in range(len(strList)):
        strList[i] = strList [int(i)]
    return strList


def squareEach(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i] = eval(nums[i])
        nums[i] = nums[i]**2
    return nums




def sumList(nums):
    b = sum(nums)
    return b





def main():
    file=open("numbers.txt","r").readline().split(" ")
    print(str(squareEach(file)))
    print(str(sumList(file)))
```

Comment: What does the `numbers.txt` file contain?

Comment: Sorry about that it consists a list of numbers.  "54 63 63 42 83 42 22 27 88 52"

seperated by spaces

Answer (score 3):

Your squareEach function modifies the original list which is passed to it.
To see what's going, consider adding a print between your function calls.

    `def main():
        file=open("numbers.txt","r").readline().split(" ")
        print(str(squareEach(file)))
        print(str(file))
        print(str(sumList(file))`

EDIT:
The simplest fix would be to use a different list for storing your square numbers inside squareEach function

```
def squareEach(nums):
    squares = []
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        num = eval(nums[i])
        squares[i] = num**2
    return squares
```

There are more efficient ways as suggested in other answers, but in your case, this appears to be the simplest fix.

Comment: Also do not forget to close the file (use with-statement).

Comment: Why is this? I thought the data would only be changed specifically within the function call & not the file variable itself. What are ways around this ? Instead of changing the list passed in should I copy them first? or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether i am helping . But whatever you are trying to do can be done as follows

```
file=open("numbers.txt","r").readline().split(" ")
print ([int (m)**2 for m in file])
print (sum([int(m) for m in file]))
```

And if you want functions

```
def squareEach(file):
    print ([int (m)**2 for m in file])
def sumList(file):
    print (sum([int(m) for m in file]))


file=open("numbers.txt","r").readline().split(" ")
squareEach(file)
sumList(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

The list `nums` is modified in `squareEach` method. Consider storing the results in a different list variable of the below sort:

```
def squareEach(nums):
    sq = list()
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        sq.append(str(int(nums[i])**2))
        # nums[i] = str(int(nums[i])**2)
    return sq
```